# Dynamic memory(calloc) and pointer to pointer [C]

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have a problem with my program. 
I want to write a program that creat a varible on dynamic memory and input number from the user.

Then I want to create a dynamic array and use the varible to the size of tha array but I saw an error.
 Why? How can I fix it?

The problem is the line: `int* numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*number));`

Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void FirstFunc();
void secondFunc(int* number);

int main(void)
{
  FirstFunc();

  getchar(); 
  return 0;
}

  void FirstFunc()
  {
    int* number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
     // check
     if (!(number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
  {
     printf("Unsuccessful malloc!/ n");
      return 1;
   }

     printf("Enter any number:");
     scanf("%d", &number);
     printf("%d", number);

     secondFunc(number);
 }

    void secondFunc(int* number)
     {
        int i = 0;
         int* numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*number));
         // check
         if (!(numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))))
         {
            printf("Unsuccessful malloc!/ n");
            return 1;
          }
          if (numbersArr)
          {
            for (i = 0; i < numbersArr + 1; i++)
          {
             scanf("%d", number);
          }
          }



         }
```

Comment: 'I saw an error' - well?  What error?  What line?  Compile. link or run time?

Comment: Sorry, I think runtime error. line:                                                                                                                        int* numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*number));

Comment: It's destroyed here anyway: 'scanf("%d", &number);'

Comment: TURN ON ALL WARNINGS AND ERRORS rebuild, tell us what the warnings/errors are.

Comment: So that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.

**First:** you are creating a pointer and allocating memory to it in `FirstFunc()`. To input it don't use &number

```
 scanf("%d", number);
 printf("%d", *number);
```

**Second:** In `secondFunc()` numbersArr is an array, you can't take loop it for numberArr + 1, instead it should be

```
for (i = 0; i < *number; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &numbersArr[i]);
}
```

To see a running demo visit this [link](http://ideone.com/OWVJhP)

Answer (score 0):

The line is wrong. If you use:

```
int* numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*number));
```

the compiler won't like it. Try to add just another variable int to take value of int that number is pointing at. This should work:

```
int size = *number;
int* numbersArr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Comment: Thank you,but I need to use the varible brofre. is it impossible to use it anyway? :(

Comment: perhaps the best in this code would be to take number as int, and not as pointer. It would be easier to work with. You just making a mess with the pointer and sparing only little memory. also, I think you are alocating same arrays twice when you are checking if the allocation was succesfull.